# Можно ли сделать вычисляемое поле со сцепкой текста?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

**Имеется:**
Таблица 1 - tst_003_tb_01_calcul - основная
Таблица 2 - tst_003_tb_02_calcul - подчинённая
Тип связи 1:М

**Вопрос**
Можно ли сделать вычисляемое поле со сцепкой текста в таблице "tst_003_tb_01_calcul" или в отдельной таблице (запросе)?
Чтобы сцепка текста происходила по условию:
Если
поле "pol_1" таблицы "tst_003_tb_01_calcul" = поле "pol_1" таблицы "tst_003_tb_02_calcul"
и
поле "idsub" таблицы "tst_003_tb_01_calcul" = поле "idsub" таблицы "tst_003_tb_02_calcul"

то сцепить значения записи поля "pol_4" таблицы "tst_003_tb_02_calcul" для соответствующего значения поля "pol_1" таблицы "tst_003_tb_01_calcul"

Дополнительные условия сцепки:
- сцепляемые значения были в кавычках (типа "< … >" или другие ) и через запятую и
- результат сцепки располагался в поле "pol_scepka" таблицы "tst_003_tb_01_calcul"

Пример результата:
< ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 1> , < ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 2> , < ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 3>

Скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выбирайте любой из этих сотен ответов, какой больше нравится http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+group_concat  (а для добавления угловых скобок воспользуйтесь concat())

Comment: @Mike Что-то сделал... Но выдаёт  ошибку
Код
SELECT t01.`idsub`, t01.`pol_1`, GROUP_CONCAT(t02.`pol_4`) AS `pol_scepka`
FROM `tst_003_tb_01_calcul` t01
INNER JOIN `tst_003_tb_02_calcul` t02 ON t02.`idsub` = t01.`idsub`
GROUP BY t01.`idsub`
 


Ошибка
Ошибка SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT t01.`idsub`, t01.`pol_1`, GROUP_CONCAT(t02.`pol_4`) AS `pol_scepka`
' at line 1 */

Не могли бы подсказать в чём проблема?

Изм.1 скрин вопроса... В Таблице "01" была ошибка

Comment: Хм. ошибку не вижу, запрос выглядит правильно. может где нибудь какой нибудь пробел, который тут не видно ... Попробуйте для начала `select * from ... join ... on ...` т.е. уберите вычисляемые колонки и group. если отработает - начинайте усложнять, возвращайте group потом начинайте перечислять необходимые поля

Comment: @Mike ok... А как понимать такие выражения -  "t01.idsub"? Я не смог разобраться, что такое "t01". Я понимаю, что это как бы ссылка (псевдоним) таблиц... Но всё таки как правильно понимать это выражение?

Comment: колонка idsub в таблице названной в запросе t01. А в from вы как раз назвали таблицу tst_003_tb_01_calcul как t01 там можно было между ними (таблицей и t01) написать `AS` если вдруг так понятней, но  в принципе слово `as` не обязательно

Comment: @Mike Сделал по другому. Причём заработало только когда удалил поле из кода поле "`t01`.`pol_1`". Рабочий вариант Код 2 'SELECT `t01`.`idsub`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT`t02`.`pol_4` ORDER BY `t02`.`pol_4` ASC SEPARATOR ' >  ') AS`scepk`
FROM `tst_003_tb_01_calcul` `t01`
LEFT JOIN `tst_003_tb_02_calcul` `t02` ON `t01`.`idsub` = `t02`.`idsub`
GROUP BY `t01`.`idsub`
'  Может этот код прояснит почему не работает код 1? Или всё равно сложно определить причину почему код 1 с ошибкой? скрин по ссылке http://prntscr.com/ejjb4j

Comment: это не ясно. если там нет пробелов то синтаксической ошибки быть не должно. А если такого поля просто нет - по хорошему должно так и сказать. можно обратные апострофы все убрать и посмотреть на случай если регистр названия не тот